# Change .html.erb file without rails framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am not sure if it  is a correct place to ask this question here but..
I deploy to heroku like this
`git push heroku`

I am not sure how it all works but it gives me long address like `green-eye-3232.herokuapp.com` and even not asking heroku password.

So I am building a website and when I finish it,  I will deploy to heroku paid account. But the thing is that client  wants to be able to add some text to html pages by himself without programming (for example if I dissapear in a month).
So will he be able to edit  text in `.html.erb` file through notepad, or from heroku  interface? Without having installed rails framework and other stuff?
If it is not a correct place to ask this question feel free to point where should I ask it.

Comment: You'll need to make a [CMS system](https://hackhands.com/9-best-ruby-rails-content-management-systems-cms/)

Answer (score 0):

The app name can be changed. You can find more information [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps)

It will be difficult for him to make edits imo.

A possible way, is to perhaps give him git access to the code repo, and  set up an auto deployment to heroku via git hooks. Then all he has to do is edit the github html page directly. You can find more about that [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#automatic-deploys).

Comment: thannks I will see))